# how to check for duplicates and rename file if there are any while copying them from another source

Tags: linux, bash

It's a script in bash, it copies files from one directory into another but there may be duplicates in a sub-directory. So while copying, it should recognize if a another file has the same name and if so - change the name of the file that is being copied. 
I tried this

```
for i in $1; do
    find $i -type f -name img*.jpg -exec cp {} $2 \;
    for j in $2; do
        find $j -type f -name $i | while read filename; do if test "$i"="$j"; then mv $i new_filename; fi done
    done
done
```

but I get a error message saying a filename should not contain slashes which is a bit weird... am a complete beginner, please do comment if you put any code. thanks.

Comment: Can you give a sample directory structure?

Comment: Perhaps see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17293/4499.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$1` should be a directory list, because it is the first parameter after find. OK? 
In your first find you must quote the asterisk: `-name 'img*.jpg'`
Then you copy into **directory** `$2`.
Therefore, `$2` in your second for is a directory, and only one.
If your intention is to look at every **file** in `$2`, use `for j in $2/*` And then, `find $2 -type f -name $i | while` ...
BTW, if chance is that names may contain spaces, use double quotes around parameters.